# Flutter - Page with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin cause unnecessary build

Tags: flutter

I am having this issue [github link.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72908) What happens is if a widget uses TickerProviderStateMixin then it gets rebuilt when a page navigation occurs. I have a very complex page and rebuilding the whole page causes a UI jank on page navigation. If I do not rebuild then everything is fine no janks. Is there a workaround for this? It seems to me that this is some sort of an internal flutter bug or unexpected behaviour?

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PageA(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  PageA({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _PageAState createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  void toPageB() {
    //tabController.animateTo(1);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PageB();
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Page A");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Text(
              "Tab A",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
            ),
            Text(
              "Tab B",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
            )
          ],
          controller: tabController,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: toPageB,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Page B");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page A"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Page A"),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if you don't use `TickerProviderStateMixin`, the rebuild can happen and that's just Flutter way of doing things. You can't do much about it.

Comment: well i guess im just disappointed that flutter was not able to hold my tree structure. i had around 400 containers and some animated objects.

Comment: 400 Containers in a List or Column or somewhere else?

Comment: Inside a page view

Comment: Ok, so are you using `PageView.builder` or some other constructor?

Comment: No builders but my page is very small height wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  void didChangeDependencies() {}
```

just add the code to prevent the rebuild, I dont know the side effect, but this walk around works for my app.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I used before.

Change your Page A like

```
class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  PageA({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _PageAState createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  TabController tabController;

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  // }

  void toPageB() {
    tabController.animateTo(1);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PageB();
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Page A");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CustomTabBar(
          tabs: [
            Text(
              "Tab A",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
            ),
            Text(
              "Tab B",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
            )
          ],
          controller: (controller) {
            tabController = controller;
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: toPageB,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And add a new class `CustomTabBar`

```dart
class CustomTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTabBar({
    this.controller,
    this.tabs,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Function(TabController)? controller;
  final List<Widget>? tabs;

  @override
  _CustomTabBarState createState() => _CustomTabBarState();
}

class _CustomTabBarState extends State<CustomTabBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController =
        TabController(length: widget.tabs?.length ?? 0, vsync: this);
    if (widget.controller != null) {
      widget.controller!(tabController);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBar(
      tabs: widget.tabs ?? [],
      controller: tabController,
    );
  }
}
```

It should fix the issue that Page A rebuild

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing this. I could not understand, how does this help with the rebuild? Could you give more context?

Comment: First of all, it need to keep the animation, so you need `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`. As we know `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` will call the UI to update. Therefore,  create a child `CustomTabBar` and make all UI change  inside the `CustomTabBar` when animation is playing. You can see only the `CustomTabBar` use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` and when it in initState it will pass the tabController to Page A. When Page A calling the tabController to play aniamtion, it actually let the child `CustomTabBar` to rebuild

Comment: this restricts the ability to use AnimationController in PageA

Comment: Unless you have other animation widget in page A, but the solution is the same. Make the animation widget become a new custom starefulwidget and pass the controller back to page A in its initstate

Comment: So basically what you are suggesting is I have one widget with TickerProviderStateMixin and create multiple animation controllers and pass them around to sub child widgets? Sorry I'm having hard time understanding your solution :(

Comment: Let say, In page A, you have tab bar and a text want to use animation. But you just want to play the animation but not to rebuild page A. So you need to create a custom tab bar stateful widget with TickerProviderStateMixin and custom text stateful widget with TickerProviderStateMixin. The key is you should declare and create the animation controller in each custom class. In their initState, there will be the function to pass the controller to page A (you can see my code in CustomTabBar initState, it call a function pass to page A not receive from Page A). It only need to declare it in page A

Comment: `tabController = TabController(length: widget?.tabs?.length ?? 0, vsync: this);` this code should use in the custom class not page A. In page A, you can see `controller: (controller) {
            tabController = controller;
          },` to get the controller back. What you need is ONE page A and few custom class playing animals with  TickerProviderStateMixin and their own controller. The controller should declare, create and pass to page A.